# Graph scale from polynomial

Tags: java, graph

I have to create a program that linearly approximates any polynomial and I was wondering if there was an algorithm to automatically scale the x-axis and the y-axis so that the graph doesn't look too stretched out or shrunken?

Comment: Yes, this is called linear interpolation. You probably will need to base it on the aspect ratio of your JFrame and/or the resolution of the monitor.

Comment: Make some usecases and consider how they should be shown.

Comment: Post some code and show us what you've got.